# Properties of rad A in rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ rings,  $f: A \to B$  is a surjective homomorphism. Then $f(\operatorname{rad}A) \subset \operatorname{rad}B$ and construct an example where the inclusion is strict.

By $\operatorname{rad}A$ denote the Jacobson radical of $A$, i.e. the intersection of all maximal ideals of $A$.

But how can I prove this ? If $x \in f(\operatorname{rad}A)$ then there exist $y \in \operatorname{rad}A$ such that $f(x)=y$ and then how can I use the surjectivity of $f$ ?

Could someone help me do this please. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Do your $A$ and $B$ have $1$?

Comment: No. I think they don't have 1 cause the book just say A and B ring, but the book is matsumura and is commutative algebra

Comment: $f$ is surjective implies that the inverse image of a maximal ideal is maximal. This is key to an easy proof.

Comment: If it is Matsumura, they *definitely* have a $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, for a unital ring $R$, you can use the characterization that the Jacobson radical $J(R)$  is the set $\{x\in R:1+RxR\subset R^\times\}$. Mouse over below if you get stuck.

> Let $x\in J(A)$. To see $f(x)\in J(B)$, you need $1+bf(x)b'$ is a unit in $B$ for any $b,b'\in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, $b=f(a)$ and $b'=f(a')$ for some $a,a'\in A$. Then $1+bf(x)b'=1+f(a)f(x)f(a')=f(1+axa').$ Since $x\in J(A)$, $1+axa'$ is a unit in $A$, hence the image under $f$ is a unit in $B$. So $f(x)\in J(B)$.

As for an example where the inclusion is strict, you can show $J(\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$ (this is obvious from the above characterization). It's also known $J(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})=6\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ (you can compute this by taking the intersection of maximal ideals), so the canonical surjection gives such an example.

Comment: The rings are also commutative. We do not need that non-commutative characterisation.

Comment: @MooS Thanks, I know, but I figure it's easy enough to prove it without the commutativity assumption, so might as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** If $\mathfrak m \subset B$ is maximal, $f^{-1}(\mathfrak m) \subset A$ is maximal, since $f$ is surjective. Thus we have $\operatorname{rad}(A) \subset f^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$. Take it from here.